# axios vuejs type error getting json data

Tags: json, vue.js, vuejs2, typeerror, axios

I have the following code that works flawlessly...

```
<html>
 <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id='app'>
  <input type='text' v-model='keyword' placeholder='search item'>
  <button>automotive</button>
  <div v-for="item in filteredItemList">

<p>{{item.name}}</p>
  </div>
  </div>
      <script>

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    keyword:'',
    itemList:[]
  },
             created: function() {
            this.loaddata();
            },
            methods: {
                loaddata: function(){
                  var vueapp = this;
                    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(function (response){
                        vueapp.itemList = response.data;
                    })
                },
            },

  computed:{
    filteredItemList(){
      return this.itemList.filter((item) => {
        return item.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.keyword.toLowerCase());
      });
    }
  }
})
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, when I change the URL to fetch real data I get the following error:

> 'vue.js:597 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: this.itemList.filter is not a function" (found in Root)'

I do not understand why it is doing this. If anyone has any ideas on this and how to help I would really, really, really appreciate it! :)

the following is the json I am trying to get in testjson.php:

```
[{"id":"1658","itemId":"60255","name":"EasterEggCrack","name_short":"Easter Eggs","image":"1","vid":"1","duration":"6","designer":"Scott","Automotive":"0","Backgrounds":"0","Church":"0","Community":"1","Money":"0","Food":"0","Gaming":"0","Healthcare":"0","Holidays":"1","Sports":"0","Patriotic":"0","Retail":"0","Education":"0","Misc":"0","terms":"easter, chick, chicken, decorations, happy, egg, crack, split, spring, allergies, holiday, community, pastel, ","dateAdded":"2018-03-20"},{"id":"1657","itemId":"64748","name":"StPattysDay","name_short":"Patrick's Day","image":"1","vid":"1","duration":"10","designer":"Scott","Automotive":"0","Backgrounds":"0","Church":"0","Community":"0","Money":"0","Food":"0","Gaming":"0","Healthcare":"0","Holidays":"1","Sports":"0","Patriotic":"0","Retail":"0","Education":"0","Misc":"0","terms":"st patricks day, gold, pot, pot of gold, green, clover, leprechaun, hat, shine, holiday","dateAdded":"2018-03-07"}]
```

Heres a copy of the page that doesn't work:

```
<html>
 <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id='app'>
  <input type='text' v-model='keyword' placeholder='search item'>
  <button>automotive</button>
  <div v-for="item in filteredItemList">

<p>{{item.name}}</p>
  </div>
  </div>
      <script>

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    keyword:'',
    itemList:[]
  },
             created: function() {
            this.loaddata();
            },
            methods: {
                loaddata: function(){
                  var vueapp = this;
                    axios.get('testjson.php').then(function (response){
                        vueapp.itemList = response.data;
                    })
                },
            },

  computed:{
    filteredItemList(){
      return this.itemList.filter((item) => {
        return item.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.keyword.toLowerCase());
      });
    }
  }
})
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code seams valid. Have you checked your testjson.php from the browser to see if it loads correctly or `console.log(response.data)` to verify the json is valid? If you use chrome right click to inspect and click on the network tab

Comment: Your `testjson.php` is most likely not returning a JSON array properly.

Comment: What do you mean by shooting from the hip?

Comment: The issue is most likely the response from your test server. I'd check the browsers web-inspector>network tab to ensure the JSON is properly being returned